# jQuery fadeIn Not Working on iPhones

Tags: jquery, iphone, safari

Pretty basic fade in/out. Simply will not work on any iPhone. Works fine in Safari desktop version. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
            <div class="maploading" style="float:right;margin-top:17px;">
                <img src="whatever.jpg" />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var $kds = jQuery.noConflict();
                $kds("div.maploading").hide();
                $kds("#addressSubmit").click(function() { 
                    $kds("div.maploading").fadeIn(100).delay(1200).fadeOut(400); 
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't know if this will work for everyone. Apparently, setting the object you wish to show/hide requires 'position:absolute'. It should be worth noting this might substantially change your element positioning.

```
        <div class="maploading" style="position:absolute;display:none;">
            <img src="whatever.jpg" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $kds = jQuery.noConflict();
            $kds("#addressSubmit").click(function() { 
                $kds("div.maploading").fadeIn(100).delay(1200).fadeOut(400); 
            });
        </script>
```

Stupid Apple devices.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem using Safari on IOS 13 (writing a PWA App). I got around it by using CSS 3 animations

```
 .page-element {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```