# jQuery content scroller fails to show list items after first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a news scroller which rotates through an array of news items, fading them in and out. For some reason, on mobile devices, it malfunctions after the first item is displayed, hiding all other items. Chrome DevTools tells me that they fail to show because their `display` is set to `none`. My question is, why would this be working on desktops, but malfunctioning on mobile devices (namely iPhone 6/7/8)? Here is the code used to show the items:

```
newsArr = ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4'];

$.each(newsArr, function(i) {
  $('ul#newsScroller').append('<li class="news-item">' + newsArr[i] + '</li>');
  $('#allNewsDiv').append('<div class="all-news-item"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/r8nu1zb2gpzd92k/Ball%20Icon.png" alt="" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; position: relative; top: 2px;" width="20" height="20"><div class="all-news-item-text">' + newsArr[i] + '</div></div>');
});

// Determine the height of the li element and set the scroller to that height
var maxScrollerHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul#newsScroller li').map(function() {
  return $(this).outerHeight(true);
}).get());
$('#newsScroller').css({
  'height': (maxScrollerHeight) + 'px',
  'opacity': '1'
});

// Hide li elements initially
$('ul#newsScroller li').css({
  'display': 'none'
});

(function() {

  var newsItems = $(".news-item");
  var newsItemsIndex = -1;

  function showNextNewsItems() {
    ++newsItemsIndex;
    newsItems.eq(newsItemsIndex % newsItems.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextNewsItems);
  }

  showNextNewsItems();

})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shaneswebdevelopment/k2ptfhqz/

Comment: Is there a sensible alternative to hiding subsequent news items with something other than `display:none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I changed from using the `display` style attribute to using `opacity`. Each news item is set to `position: absolute` and faded in and out like so:

```
// Hide li elements initially
$('ul#newsScroller li').css({
  'opacity': '0'
});

(function() {

  var newsItems = $(".news-item");
  var newsItemsIndex = -1;

  function showNextNewsItems() {
    ++newsItemsIndex;
    newsItems.eq(newsItemsIndex % newsItems.length)
      .fadeTo(2000,1)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeTo(2000,0,showNextNewsItems);
  }

  showNextNewsItems();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an article about a problem with fading in/out on the iphone:

[jQuery fadeIn Not Working on iPhones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411520/jquery-fadein-not-working-on-iphones)

Maybe you have to set the position of your list to relative.

```
newsArr = ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4'];

$.each(newsArr, function(i) {
  $('ul#newsScroller').append('<li class="news-item">' + newsArr[i] + '</li>');
  $('#allNewsDiv').append('<div class="all-news-item"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/r8nu1zb2gpzd92k/Ball%20Icon.png" alt="" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; position: relative; top: 2px;" width="20" height="20"><div class="all-news-item-text">' + newsArr[i] + '</div></div>');
});

// Determine the height of the li element and set the scroller to that height
var maxScrollerHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $('ul#newsScroller li').map(function() {
  return $(this).outerHeight(true);
}).get());
$('#newsScroller').css({
  'height': (maxScrollerHeight) + 'px',
  'opacity': '1'
});

// Hide li elements initially
$('ul#newsScroller li').css({
  'display': 'none',
  'position': 'relative'
});

(function() {
  var newsItems = $(".news-item");
  var newsItemsIndex = -1;

  function showNextNewsItems() {
    ++newsItemsIndex;
    newsItems.eq(newsItemsIndex % newsItems.length)
  .fadeIn(2000)
  .delay(2000)
  .fadeOut(2000, showNextNewsItems);
  }

  showNextNewsItems();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the article and the suggestion. changing the position did not work though.